# How to add multiple integer values from firebase in Android Studio

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

Here is my main `HomeActivity` and `AddUserDetails` class to handle this.

Can you please give me some suggestions so that my app will not crash and I can total the sum of integer values.

```java
        public class homePage extends AppCompatActivity {
        
            TextView cashValue;
            DatabaseReference TotalIncome;
    
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
                cashValue = findViewById(R.id.cashValue);
        
                TotalIncome = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Add Income User Data");
                getData();
        
            }
        
            private  void getData(){
                TotalIncome.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    
         @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        Integer total=0;
        
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
                            AddUserDetails userdata = dataSnapshot.getValue(AddUserDetails.class);
                            Integer cost = Integer.valueOf(userdata.getAmount());
                            total = total+cost;
                        }
        
                        cashValue.setText(""+total);
        
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        
                    }
                });
        
            }
        
        }
```

Please see an image from my firebase
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You added a direct integer to textView that's why it throws `Resources$NotFoundException` exeption. Just change your `textView` code from

```
cashValue.setText(""+total);
```

to this below

```
cashValue.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Let me know if not solved yet.